# Sharepoint formula to increase count of Name column

Tags: microsoft-excel, sharepoint

Looking for a formula to increase count based on times data appears in column.

I’m getting a syntax error trying
=COUNTIF([Name]:[Name],[Name])

Example:

### Name / Formula

---

Jon/   1

---

Jon/   2

---

Sam/   1

---

Jon/   3

---

Alan/  1

---

Sam/  2

---

Jon/  4

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center. Here is a guide on [ask] and [answer]. We are not a free coding service but a community of people interested in computers that are willing to share their knowledge and experience. If you have already tried something please post it here, otherwise this question is likey to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

If your table is called `Table1` try this:

```
=COUNTIF(Table1[[#Headers],[Name]]:[@Name],[@Name])
```

Comment: COUNTIF is not a function in Sharepoint unfortunately